# Stuck on 301 redirect with variables php

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm trying to write a 301 in our .htaccess file but can't get it working. We have url's like the following…

```
http://www.example.com/?cat=tree-category

http://www.example.com/?cat=food-category
```

We would like to change these to

```
http://www.example.com/directory/listings/tree-category

http://www.example.com/directory/listings/food-category
```

Could anyone help please, it would be very appreciated!

James

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^cat=([a-zA-Z0-9\-]*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/directory/listings/%1 [R=301,L]
```

Check out: http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2009/01/apache-query-string-redirects/

Comment: Hi Brian, I'm afraid not. I can't figure it out - I'm using Wordpress which I know has some built in redirects but it should still work.

Comment: Want to post your .htaccess file? We can't really help without more info.